# Twisted-18.9.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python

When I am installing Twisted package using this command:

```
pip3.7 install /root/Twisted-18.9.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

It throw this error:

```
Twisted-18.9.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

My OS is redhat 7,Python3.7 `/usr/local/python3/bin/python3.7`.How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `win` in `Twisted-18.9.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` says that it is for Windows.

You should use `Twisted-18.9.0.tar.bz2` from [Twisted 18.9.0](https://pypi.org/project/Twisted/#files) for your Linux machine.